# Why is $\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{n-2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n e_i^2\right] = \sigma^2$?

Tags: variance, least-squares, standard-deviation, residuals

The context that we are presented with a linear model
$$Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_i + \epsilon_i,$$
where $\epsilon_i \texttt{~} \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$.

We obtain predictions for $X_i$ by plugging in to
$$\hat{Y}_i = \hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1X_i,$$
where the hatted variables are estimates for the true values.

We then define
$$e_i := Y_i - \hat{Y}_i.$$

It is then claimed, in [this book](https://leanpub.com/regmods) (and [this video](https://youtu.be/ZE3a4OZFWPA?t=1m14s)) that
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{n-2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n e_i^2\right] = \sigma^2$$

Where can I find a proof of this statement?

I've tried working through it myself, but so far without success:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{n-2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n e_i^2\right] &= \frac{1}{n-2}\mathbb{E}\left[\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (Y_i - \hat{Y}_i)^2\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{n-2}\mathbb{E}\left[\sum\limits_{i=1}^n Y_i^2 -2\sum\limits_{i=1}^nY_i\hat{Y}_i +\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\hat{Y}_i^2\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{n-2}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}\left[Y_i^2\right] -2\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}\left[Y_i\hat{Y}_i\right] +\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}\left[\hat{Y}_i^2\right]\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{n-2}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}\left[Y_i^2\right] -2\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\hat{Y}_i^2 +\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\hat{Y}_i^2\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{n-2}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(\sigma^2+\mathbb{E}\left[Y_i\right]^2\right) -2\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\hat{Y}_i^2 +\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\hat{Y}_i^2\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{n-2}\left(n\sigma^2 + \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \hat{Y}_i^2 -2\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\hat{Y}_i^2 +\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\hat{Y}_i^2\right)
\\&= \frac{n\sigma^2}{n-2}.
\end{align*}

However, this is evidently wrong, and I can't see where I've made a mistake.

Comment: Strange things start to happen when you remove expectation operators in the step from the 3rd to the 4th line.

Comment: You have two different Y parameters, the observation $Y_i$ and the modeled version $\hat{Y_i}$ , but you should also have something like the theoretic mean ($Y_{\mu,i} = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_i$), such that $$Y_i = Y_{\mu,i} + \epsilon_i $$ and $$Y_i = \hat{Y_{i}} + e_i $$ So three type of expressions for Y. Then eventually you could show something like $E(\sigma^2-s^2) = E((\hat{Y_i}-Y_{\mu,i})^2)$

Comment: also, likely this question may already be answered on this site https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=bessel%27s+correction